# Show only local orders in WooCommerce admin page

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

In my shop, customers can buy the same product from several locations. Each location has its own shop_manager, so I want every shop_manager can only see the orders where the selected variation matches their location (e.g. "shop_manager_min", from Minnesota, can only see orders where variation "min" has been selected; "shop_manager_tex", from Texas, can only see orders with "tex" variation and so on).

To do so, I tried the next code:

```
    add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'orders_by_location' );
    function orders_by_location( $query ) {
//check if user role is shop_manager to continue
        if(isset(wp_get_current_user()->roles[0]) && wp_get_current_user()->roles[0] == 'shop_manager'){
//gets the 3 character string code for the shop manager location
            $location = substr(wp_get_current_user()->user_login, -3);
//query for all the orders where the variation matches the shop manager location
            $query->set( 'meta_query', array( 
                          array( 
                                  'key' => 'attribute_pa_location', 
                                  'value' => $location, 
                                  'compare' => '=' 
            ) ) );  
        return $query; }}
```

However, I got nothing back from this query, no orders are shown. What I am doing wrong?

---

I have tried the next query to order orders by location, and it works just perfectly:

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'orders_by_location' );
function orders_by_location( $query ) {
    if(isset(wp_get_current_user()->roles[0]) && wp_get_current_user()->roles[0] == 'shop_manager'){
        $query->set('orderby', 'attribute_pa_location' );
        $query->set('order', 'DESC' );
        return $query; }}
```

With the previous, I see attribute_pa_location exists and it is accessible by the query. I also echoed the attribute_pa_location value and the value in $location, and both are the exactly same!!! However, the query is not giving anything back and no orders are shown in the shop_manager admin order page.

---

I did the same first query using `_customer_user` instead of `attribute_pa_sede` and worked perfectly. If the query procedure is fine and the meta key is also fine, why is not working when I use them together???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found that the problem is that the attribute location is not part of the order attributes (but part of the product attributes). As a turnaround, I copied the location into the transaction id during checkout using the next action in functions.php:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'update_order_id', 30, 2 );
function update_order_id( $order, $posted_data ) {
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {$location = $item->get_meta("pa_location");}
    $order->set_transaction_id($location); }
```

After that, I just query:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'orders_by_location', 100 );
function orders_by_location( $query ) {
    if(isset(wp_get_current_user()->roles[0]) && wp_get_current_user()->roles[0] == 'shop_manager'){
        $location = substr(wp_get_current_user()->user_login, -3);
        $query->set('post_type', 'shop_order' );
        $query->set('post_status', array('wc-on-hold', 'wc-processing') );
        $query->set('meta_key', '_transaction_id' );
        $query->set('meta_value', $location ); } 
    return $query; }
```